# jquery, select all options button not working in IE but works in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, perl, cgi

somewhere in my cgi code, I generate this:

```
my $PARAMETER_HTML .= "<select name='parameters' id='parameters' size='10' multiple='multiple'>";
foreach my $values (sort @PARA_VALUES)
{
    $PARAMETER_HTML .= "<option value=\"" . $values . "\" >" . $values  . "</option>";
}
$PARAMETER_HTML .= qq|</select>|;
```

Some where later, I generate a button:

```
<button id="select_all1"><b>Select All<br>Parameters</b></button>
```

Some where later, I generate this script code:

```
$("#select_all1").click(function() {
    $("#parameters").each(function(){ $("#parameters option").attr("selected","selected"); });                
});
```

It works in firefox but not in IE. Is there a fix for IE (tested on version 7)?

Comment: Shouldn't `$PARAMETER_HTML .= qq|</select>|;` say `$PARAMETER_HTML .= "</select>";`

Comment: Do you have multiple HTML elements with an "parameters" ID?

Comment: Also, inside a each() method's callback, we usually refer to the current element via the `this` value.

Comment: Also, setting the "selected" attribute to true is a better choice: attr("selected", true)

Comment: thanks for all the help, i debug the coding to a missing </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that `$("#parameters").each` loop; it's not doing anything, as #parameters refers to a single element (the select element).

Second of all, the minimal version below works fine for me across browsers including IE7.  I would check your page source to make sure your generated HTML is correct, and then try to pare things down to the minimal page that works.  Then put stuff back carefully.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#select_all1").click(function() {
      $("#parameters option").attr("selected","selected");
   });
});
</script>
<button id="select_all1"><b>Select All<br>Parameters</b></button><br />

<select id="parameters" multiple="multiple">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that I would think is the use of `<button>` I replaced it with a `<div>` and it works fine in IE8 at least.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wtw4e/

**Edit:**

Well another answer says it works fine with `<button>` so it could well be the usual problem of IE being substantially more fussy about code correctness than the other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would double-check the output HTML as your code appears to run properly in FF4 and IE8. (I don't have IE7 kicking around to test on.) Here is your code running in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CXQxT/

BTW - You can simplify your jQuery. No need for the .each().

```
$('#select_all1').click(function() {
    $('#parameters option').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TWBRQ/